# Gulp: произвольный код перед gulp.series() or gulp.parallel() на примере изменения значения переменной

Tags: node.js, gulp

Каким образом следует изменить значение переменной `isDevelopment` перед запуском серии внутренних тасков?

```
// значение по умолчанию
let isDevelopment = !process.env.NODE_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';


gulp.task('Development Run', () => {

    isDevelopment = true; // происходит ошибка: The following tasks did not complete: Development Run

    gulp.series( 
        'Development Build', 
        gulp.parallel('Watch Assets And Source', 'Static Server')
    )

});

gulp.task('Production Build', () => {

    isDevelopment = false; // происходит ошибка: The following tasks did not complete: Production Build

    gulp.series( 
        gulp.parallel('styles', 'scripts')
    );

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка говорит сама за себя, нужно завершить задачу. В Gulp для этого можно вернуть callback, promise, поток.

https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/4.0/docs/API.md#gulptaskname-fn

**UPD** попробуте так

```
 // значение по умолчанию
let isDevelopment = !process.env.NODE_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';

gulp.task('Development Run', (callback) => {

    isDevelopment = true;

    gulp.series( 
        'Development Build', 
        gulp.parallel('Watch Assets And Source', 'Static Server')
    );

    callback();
});

gulp.task('Production Build', (callback) => {

    isDevelopment = false;

    gulp.series( 
        gulp.parallel('styles', 'scripts')
    );

    callback();
});
```