# Gulp sourcemaps сохранять вся историю импортов

Tags: gulp, sourcemap

Структура проекта

```
style
--components
----modal.styl
----component1.styl
----component2.styl
--mixin.styl
--main.styl
--test.styl
```

gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task('test', function () {
    return gulp.src('./style/main.styl')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(stylus())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(outputPath))
});
```

примеры на stylus

main.styl

```
@import 'mixin'
@import 'components/*'
@import 'test'
```

component1.styl

```
$widget1
    background-color #fff

    +sm()
        background-color red
```

test.styl

```
.some
    @extend $widget1
    // other styles
```

mixin.styl

```
sm()
    @media screen and (max-width 768px)
        {block}
```

browser output

[image: browser sourcemap]

Вопрос в том можно ли сделать, чтоб sourcemaps хранил историю импорта т.е. вместо `mixin.styl` 
отдавал
`test.styl - mixin.styl`, а то в таком виде не всегда ясно откуда ноги растут

**UPD** Обновил пример в соответствии с ответами

Answer (score 0):

> The exported identityMap method allows you to generate a full valid source map encoding no changes (slower, only for Javascript and CSS) instead of the default empty source map (no mappings, fast). Use this option if you get missing or incorrect mappings, e.g. when debugging.

*Используйте эту опцию, если вы получаете пропущенные или неправильные сопоставления, например, при отладке.*

```
gulp.task('javascript', function() {
  var stream = gulp.src('src/**/*.js')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      // An identity sourcemap will be generated at this step
      .pipe(sourcemaps.identityMap())
      .pipe(plugin1())
      .pipe(plugin2())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('../maps')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/scripts'));
});
```

Для Вашего случая достаточно будет заменить **.init()** на **.identityMap()**.

Другие примеры и больше настроек [тут](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sourcemaps#generate-identity-sourcemap)

Comment: Этот способ будет возвращать ссылку всегда на первый файл по вложенности или вообще не генерирует карту. Приемлемо для небольших проектов, но с большой структурой будет не удобно.
Видимо остается писать свой форк...

Comment: [Stylus SourceMap](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/sourcemaps.html) - вот еще можно попробовать, работает с этой [библиотекой](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1U1RGAehQwRypUTovF1KRlpiOFze0b-_2gc6fAH0KY0k/edit#heading=h.n05z8dfyl3yh)

Comment: Тоже видел это, опций там совсем мало, но зато есть доступ к сгенерированому sourcemap'y, есть поле для деятельности...
Это вообще возможно сделать такую карту средствами [приведенной](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1U1RGAehQwRypUTovF1KRlpiOFze0b-_2gc6fAH0KY0k/edit#) библиотеки?

Comment: обработать можно, и не так сложно, там на js же написано. Перехватывай и делай что хочешь. Надо привести к правильному формату, а если использовать последнюю библиотеку то там просто Json формат.
Я так понимаю что extends воспринимается не как отдельный файл а как "модуль" поэтому и не отображается. 
Возможно Вам могут помочь еще CodeKit и Prepros, хорошо изучите настройки этих программ. Они не используют файла настроек а настраиваются вручную

Comment: по вашему [ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/750446/189381) становится понятно что для Вас это не сложая задача, после мап.инит поправить формат так как Вам надо и передать на запись.

Comment: это всего лишь основы gulp, а вот с устройством формата sourcemap я не знаком(выглядит не понятно ... mappings: 'AAAA;EACC,QAAO,eAAP;;ACAuB;AAAA;IDGtB,QAAO,KAAP' ... ), что заводит в глубокие дебри)

Comment: далее взять json который сгенирировался автоматически и поправить как надо, потом сохранить.
Я думаю если посмотреть примеры, все станет понятно